# Joomla 3:Edit html on template page

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I have problem, with finding on Interior pages on my templete.
I want the edit html code na page on exemple here.

My joompla is 3.4 version.

1 uts.bg/joomla/
2 uts.bg/joomla/  click on "ОНЛАЙН УСЛУГИ" next "ПУБЛИКУВАЙ ТОВАР"

Result on your click uts.bg/joomla/index.php/pages/pricing.
How to edit html on this page uts.bg/joomla/index.php/pages/pricing.

I do not know how to get to this file to edit it did not find

I do not settlement this problem two days please help.

Answer (score 1):

Wow. This is not a development question. You might want to head to the joomla stackexhange site.

It's a very noob Joomla usage question. You should ask google "learn joomla" that will get you started. Joomla has no html pages.

Anyway this is a simple category blog page. it is accessed through the menu item id 336. Open menu->find the item 336 : configure to suit your needs.